# PHP 7.2 - SQL Server 2017 - Create Nested Array response

Tags: php, sql-server, soap-client, php-7.2

I have a Stored Procedure that retrieves data from a SQL Server DB.

With query result I need to populate the parameters' Array of a SOAPClient's Method

At present I'm manually creating the  Array, but I was wondering if it was possible (and worthy) to create the Array in the way required by the SOAP Method directly from TSQL:

Using PHP 7.2 - SQL Server 2017

Let me explain with an example:
this is my Query Result:

```
Array
(
    [Key] => R******l
    [Password] => c*************z
    [AccountNumber] => 0****1
    [MeterNumber] => 2******5
    [ShipTimestamp] => 2020-10-29T10:24:19+01:00
    [ServiceType] => INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY
    [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
    [PreferredCurrency] => EUR
    [Weight_Units] => KG
    [TotalWeight] => 0.02
...
)
```

While it should return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Authentication] => Array
    (
        [User] => Array
        (
            [Key] => R******l
            [Password] => c*************z
        )
    )

    [Client] => Array
    (
        [Account] => 0*******1
        [Meter] => 2*******5
    )

    [Shipment] => Array
    (
        [ShipTimestamp] => 2020-10-29T10:41:26+01:00
        [DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
        [ServiceType] => INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY
        [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
        [PreferredCurrency] => EUR
        [TotalWeight] => Array
        (
            [Units] => KG
            [Value] => 0.02
        )
    )
    ...
)
```

Is it possible and worthy?

Comment: If you need that structure just do a key mapping after the query.

Comment: Sorry.. what do you mean? can make a small example? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return one row with one JSON column using `FOR JSON PATH`<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)</sup> in SQL and in PHP `json_decode($json, true)`<sup>[3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)</sup> with `$assoc` param set to `true` to decode JSON as array.

```sql
SELECT (
  SELECT user_key [Authentication.User.Key]
       , user_password  [Authentication.User.Password]
       , client_account [Client.Account]
       , client_meter   [Client.Meter]
      --- and so on
  FROM my_table
  FOR JSON PATH
) [json]
```

The result should be JSON

```json
{ 
 "Authentication": { "User": { "Key": "XXX", "Password": "XXX" } },
 "Client": { "Account": "YYY", "Meter": 200500 }
}
```

And now You can fetch that value in PHP, decode it and supply to SOAP.

```php
  $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = json_decode($row['json'], true);
```

But in SQL You need a special syntax to format those types:

1. **date** values `CONVERT(varchar(10), date_col, 120)` -
   `120` results in `2020-10-29 11:32:00` format, `varchar(10)` trim just date part, `varchar(20)` gets whole date+time<sup>[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#j-using-convert-with-datetime-data-in-different-formats)</sup>
2. **boolean** values `CAST(boolean_col as bit)` (`0 -> false`, `1 -> true`)

**More info:**

1. SQL: [Format query results as JSON with FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. SQL: [CAST and CONVERT with datetime in different formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#j-using-convert-with-datetime-data-in-different-formats)
3. PHP: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: hmmm.. did not thought dot notation could be used for json parsing.
Will try ASAP
Thanks

Comment: SQL Server (2016+) gives few options to use `FOR JSON` - one is `PATH` where You can define nesting in columns names, other is `AUTO` where nesting depends on JOIN-s and APPLY-ies

Comment: Works Great and have a script much more clean!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As asked for an example, this can be also done with a mapping.

Data defined as

```
$data = [
    'Key'               => 'R******l',
    'Password'          => 'c*************z',
    'AccountNumber'     => '0****1',
    'MeterNumber'       => '2******5',
    'ShipTimestamp'     => '2020-10-29T10:24:19+01:00',
    'ServiceType'       => 'INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY',
    'PackagingType'     => 'YOUR_PACKAGING',
    'PreferredCurrency' => 'EUR',
    'Weight_Units'      => 'KG',
    'TotalWeight'       => '0.02',
];
```

Mapping defined with a hash table. The name may be transformed and groups may me as deep as wanted.

```
$mapping = [
    'Key'               => ['name' => 'Key',               'group' => ['Authentication', 'User']],
    'Password'          => ['name' => 'Password',          'group' => ['Authentication', 'User']],
    'AccountNumber'     => ['name' => 'Account',           'group' => ['Client']],
    'MeterNumber'       => ['name' => 'Meter',             'group' => ['Client']],
    'ShipTimestamp'     => ['name' => 'ShipTimestamp',     'group' => ['Shipment']],
    'ServiceType'       => ['name' => 'ServiceType',       'group' => ['Shipment']],
    'PackagingType'     => ['name' => 'PackagingType',     'group' => ['Shipment']],
    'PreferredCurrency' => ['name' => 'PreferredCurrency', 'group' => ['Shipment']],
    'Weight_Units'      => ['name' => 'Units',             'group' => ['Shipment', 'TotalWeight']],
    'TotalWeight'       => ['name' => 'Value',             'group' => ['Shipment', 'TotalWeight']],
];
```

Now a simple routine to remap the data by the mapping table and put to `$mappedData`.

```
$mappedData = [];
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $map = $mapping[$key];
    $root = array_shift($map['group']);
    krsort($map['group']);
    $value = [$map['name'] => $value];
    foreach($map['group'] as $group) {
        $value = [$group => $value];
    }
    $new[$root] = $value;
    $mappedData = array_replace_recursive ($mappedData, $new);
}
```

Which looks like this when executed

```
Array
(
    [Authentication] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [Key] => R******l
                    [Password] => c*************z
                )

        )

    [Client] => Array
        (
            [Account] => 0****1
            [Meter] => 2******5
        )

    [Shipment] => Array
        (
            [ShipTimestamp] => 2020-10-29T10:24:19+01:00
            [ServiceType] => INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY
            [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
            [PreferredCurrency] => EUR
            [TotalWeight] => Array
                (
                    [Units] => KG
                    [Value] => 0.02
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hi Markus, Thanks for your effort.
Jan solution is better since allows to remove a lot of code in the PHP page since just need a single row, and require just a little extra work in the Stored Procedure, but I never used a mapping solution and I think it will be useful in another function I need to write.
Thanks Again!

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree to his solution. He got my thumbs up. Both do have an another approach and even it's pros and cons. But the most important thing is about learning new things like mapping and query transformation.